# Add Text to Microsoft Office Content Control Date Picker

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

I am creating a template document that allows a user to pick a date and it will insert the date in the document with some formatted text.

i.e. if the person picked today's date, it would output `14th day of March, 2016`

So in the 'Display date like this' field I inputted `dth day of MMMM, yyyy` but it outputted like `14t12 14a16 of March, 2016` because `h` corresponds to Hour, `d` corresponded to date, and `y` corresponds to a 2-digit year.

Is there any way to add text without adding the extra info?

[image]

Edit: Also is there anyway to automatically add the suffix to a #? i.e. if the date is `2` it would add `nd` after or if date it is `4` it would add `th` after.

Comment: Have you tried putting "th day of" between quotes or single quotes or whatever masking your program allows

Comment: Wrapping each word in single quotes did the trick i.e. `'th' 'day' 'of'`. If you submit as answer i'll accept

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each word in single quotes

i.e. 'th' 'day' 'of'.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not possible without using a macro. The closest you will probably get is the following format:

```
d "day of" mmmm, yyyy
```

But this would not automatically add the date suffix you want. In other words, using your example, the above would result in:

14 day of March, 2016

You could either live with that, or change the formatting to something that may be more acceptable.

Another option would be to use VBA and a macro to determine the correct suffix and add it in.